# SQL query based on list from another query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to build a query that will generate a list of records based on the results of a very similar query.

Here are the details and examples

**Query 1**: Generate a list if part #'s in a specific location of the warehouse.

**Query 2**: Use the list of part #'s generated in #1 to show all locations for the list of part #'s, assuming they will be in both the location specified in #1 and other locations.

Query 1 looks like this:

```
Select
    ItemMaster.ItemNo, BinInfo.BIN, ItemDetail.Qty, ItemDetail.Whouse_ID
From
    ((ItemDetail
Left Join 
    ItemMaster on ItemMaster.ID=ItemDetail.Item_ID)
Left Join 
    BinInfo on BinInfo.ID = ItemDetail.Bin_ID)
Where  
    ItemDetail.Whouse_ID  = '1'
    And BinInfo.Bin = 'VLM';
```

Query 2 needs to be almost identical except the `ItemMaster.ItemNo` list will come from query #1.

Any help here would be great. I don't know if I need to learn Unions, Nested Queries, or what.

Answer (score 2):

1. make sure that your first query returns the list of ids that you need.
2. then write the second query with the `WHERE id IN (...)` syntax:

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN
    (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE...) -- first query
```